# How would be better to make an adaptation, scaling max-width, or scaling font-size?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm beginner in coding, so I'm just practicing, but every time I make screen smaller, I find a problem that text is going to the hell. How can I fix it?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: please post the photo with stack imgur. when I click your link I'm asked to log in to google

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code ? A working example ? Thank you

Comment: Imgur doesn't work to me:( But guy below already helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'going to the hell', but if you mean it's adapting to the amount of space left by moving to a new line, that is the natural order of things in HTML.

If you don't want that to happen and you want it to get cropped, you can set

```
white-space: nowrap; /* In CSS btw */
```

To get a better understanding of the white-space property, check out [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), they have a simple demo too.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Yeah, is kind of thing I was searching for, thanks!

Comment: @Alex Glad it helped ;- ) also it is recommended that you mark it as the answer to help other people having the same question